# add leading zero to simple timestamp addition JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I am trying to write a javascript function to sum up two timestamp strings, like `00:04:02` and `00:05:43`

I have this function which works, but returns a value like: `0:9:45`, I'm trying to improve it so there is a leading zero for the minutes section so it looks more like: `0:09:45` but im having trouble doing so and was wondering if anyone could help me:

```js
function sum(date1, date2){
    date1 = date1.split(":");
    date2 = date2.split(":");
    const result = [];
  
    date1.reduceRight((carry,num, index) => {
      const max = [24,60,60][index];
      const add =  +date2[index];
      result.unshift( (+num+add+carry) % max );
      return Math.floor( (+num + add + carry) / max );
    },0);
  
   return result.join(":");
  }
  
  
  console.log(sum('00:05:43', '00:04:02'))
```

Comment: `0:09:45` looks like `0:09:45`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: if you run my code you can see the output of my sum() function is `0:9:45`,  but i want it to be `0:09:45`

Comment: My comment about the numbers is they are the same in your question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pad each digit?

```
return result.map(r => String(r).padStart(2, "0")).join(":");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the built-in `Date` methods, you don't need to parse times or do math yourself.

```js
'use strict';

function sumTimestamps(a, b) {
  const [A, B] = [a, b].map((x) => new Date('1970-01-01T' + x + '.000Z'));
  return new Date(A.getTime() + B.getTime()).toUTCString().split(' ')[4];
}

const sum = sumTimestamps('00:04:02', '00:05:43');
console.log(sum);
// => 00:09:45
```